# What happens to service using objects from activity when android kills application in the background?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I transfer static objects from activities to service. What happens when users put the app in the background and the system kills automatically the application? Will objects in `Service` class express `NullPointerException` or another problem?

Here some example:

In my `MainActivity` I send a connection object to `Service`.

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    Log.i("myinfo", "onserviceconnected bağlandı.");
    MyService.LocalBinder binder = (MyService.LocalBinder) service;
    myservice = binder.getService();
    myservice.setConnection(connection);
    mBound = true;
}
```

In Service class.

```
Connection connection;

public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
     this.connection = connection;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andersen. Are you asking about objects with the "static" keyword? I don't see anything declared static in the code sample that you provided. But by default, the service is in the same process as the Activity unless you specify the "android:process" tag on the service tag in the manifest. So no it won't necessarily crash, but all the normal dangers of using Java static variables in Android still apply.

Comment: Regarding the code sample, it is probably not advisable to pass the Connection object to the service. I'm not sure why that would be necessary.